# I need a program to read the US Census's geodatabase files

Tags: free-software, gis

I downloaded a file from [here](http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-geodatabases.html), and got something with extension `.gdb.zip`. I want to get one of the tables out of this "geodatabase" and into a format that's easily accessible to other programs; csv or some such would be the obvious goal but anything moderately open will work. The Census Bureau's description of the files is:

> TIGER Geodatabases are spatial extracts from the Census Bureau’s MAF/TIGER database for use with Esri’s ArcGIS.

Since ArcGIS for home users costs $100, and I don't want any of its features other than the ability to read this file, I'm hoping there's an open source option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.digital-geography.com/opensource-qgis-postgis-installation-the-easy-way/) is a [guide](http://www.digital-geography.com/opensource-qgis-postgis-installation-the-easy-way/) for installing [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) and [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) on Ubuntu 12.04.3.  It looks like the Open Source QGIS may be a workable solution.

Comment: I'll try this, and accept it if it works.

Comment: QGIS with SPIT accepts shapefiles (.shp and .dbf) but the data I want is in a geodatabase file (.gdb). If it's possible to import those with QGIS, that tutorial doesn't explain it.

Comment: Would you be able to work with .gpx files?  If so, it is possible to convert the .gdb files to .gpx using [GPSBabel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/) which is described [here](http://www.gpsbabel.org/htmldoc-1.4.2/fmt_gdb.html).

Comment: Looks like that'd work; not going to actually test it because I found the data I needed elsewhere.